# Testing SMS Short Codes

Tags: mobile, sms, messaging

I've got an application that sits behind a US based SMS Short Code.  I can test my application from the point of ingress into our systems to the point of egress and am confident about the functionality within those boundaries.

What I want to be able to do is extend the test to include the SMS Aggregator that is handling our short code.  I want a service provider that will allow me to send and SMS via an API to a short code.  We're working with 2 different SMS aggregators (a Tier1 and a Tier3) and both api's only allow SMS messages to be sent to long codes (10 digit numbers).  I've also tried Tiwlio's SMS API, but they also do not allow SMS messages to be sent to a short code.

Can anyone recommend a service, hardware device, or other solution that would allow us to message a short code so that we can automate testing and monitoring of our short code based applications?

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably disallowed by the aggregators due to difficulty in determining what short codes incur premium charges for MT messages.

Given that you can send to a shortcode from any GSM modem/handset with a valid SIM, why not interface with one of those and use the AT command set to send your test messages?

Comment: That could be - we have had to go through different provisioning for short codes that support FTEU, Premium and Standard - and afaik, we can't mix those 'features' on a single short code, they have to be dedicated to the feature.  Maintaining a physical phone wasn't what I was hoping for.  Thanks for your response.